# objdump in windows in order to see debug info

Tags: windows, debugging, objdump, dwarf

I need to get the addresses and member names of the variables in a .out file. I basically compiled a c program in linux using gcc and I will like to see the info of the file. There are a lot of examples on linux but I need to do it on windows.

Edit

I installed cygwin and for some reason objdump does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider installing cygwin and trying those linux examples...

Comment: objdump does not work on cygwin. or maybe I am doing something wrong. take a look at my edit. thanks for the help

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work. Please make sure binutils package is installed (if you did not choose that yourself it might not get install by default).
You may use vmware player and download a ready made linux dist. I used this technique for years. Don't like using cygwin unless for the most trivial stuff.